# Why Kafka consumer freezes on Node failure while Producer stays unaffected?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and trying to create a Kafka cluster with 3 nodes for High Availability.

I have followed [this guide](https://codeforgeek.com/how-to-setup-multi-node-multi-broker-kafka-cluster-in-aws/) and I have done the setup on Google Compute Instance (GCP VMs).

I tried creating topics with different `--replication-factor`.
Here is an example with replication-factor=3. I have tried the values 1 and 2 as well.

```sh
# With replication factor-3
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create \
  --bootstrap-server xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9092,yy.yyy.yyy.yy:9092,zzz.zz.zz.zzz:9092 \
  --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic sample-topic
```

This is what my consumer code looks like:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'sample-topic',
    bootstrap_servers=[
        'yyy.yy.yy.yyy'
    ],

    client_id="sample-client-name",
    auto_offset_reset="earliest",
    group_id="sample-group-name")

for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

This is what my producer code looks like:

```
from time import sleep
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=[
        'xxx.xx.xx.xxx', 'yyy.yy.yy.yyy', 'zzz.zz.zz.zzz'])
for i in range(1000):
    message = str.encode("Message: " + str(i))
    producer.send('sample-topic', value=message)
    print("sent: {}".format(i))
    sleep(5)
```

[`xxx.xx.xx.xxx`, `yyy.yy.yy.yyy`, `zzz.zz.zz.zzz` above are the IP addresses of the VMs]

Initially, the setup works pretty well. Now I start stopping the VMs (always keeping 2 VMs alive. Whenever I want to stop another VM I make sure at least two VMs are alive).

The producer code had the same `bootstrap_servers` as consumer code. I have tried keeping only 1 and 2 servers inside `bootstrap_servers` but it fails the same way for at least one of the VM going down( tried keeping all three VMs down one after another, making sure I'll have 2 VMs working).

Kafka consumers freeze because of stopping the VMs (only one VM down at a time, other two are brought up before stopping the targeted VM)

Is there any configuration I am missing? How to make the consumer stay intact like the producer?

Comment: What's the replication factor of the consumer offsets topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read that linked post correctly, it doesn't mention that `offsets.topic.replication.factor` will have to be increased as well.

Otherwise, stopping the broker that holds the single replica will cause consumers fail to commit / lookup offsets

Comment: You're godsent!!!! Worked like charm! I had to configure the producer to send messages to all of the servers and tried taking down the node which was mentioned in `bootstrap_servers` of the consumer. It is still working without any problems.

Comment: I added the producer code in my question as well. The producer is sending messages like (`Message: 0`, `Message: 1`, `Message: 2` ...). I noticed on stopping one of the other VMs (keeping 2 VMs always healthy), consumer hangs for some time and then resumes. However, it misses a few messages. It is not figurable from the `offset number` as it seems to be correct (`offset:156` after `offset:155`) but I can see in the console after `Message 155` my consumer directly gets `Message 174`. Do you happen to know the cause of this?

Comment: On the topic, `min.insync.replicas=2` and on the producer `acks=all` could be configured to ensure that a message is ensured to be replicated across more than the leader partition. Otherwise, you could have unclean leader election when a replica is down.